# Does C# have a way of casting a double array to a string similar to the C++ cast to a char*?

Tags: c#, c++

I have inherited C++ code that casts a double array to a char* as shown below. In C#, I have not been able to generate a string from an array of doubles that matches the string generated by the C++ cast. In C#, is there someway to generate a string from a double array that would match the string created in C++ where a simple cast to char* is done? The result of the C++ cast appears to be some kind of binary data.

I want to replace the C++ code that creates the string with C# code that will generate the same string and store it in a database memo field. I want to keep the C++ code that retrieves the string from the database memo field and converts it to a double array for use in calculations.

C++ code that casts the double array Darray to a char *:

```
    char*s = (char*)Darray
```

I have tried several things in C# that didn't create the desired string including (obvious compile error):

```
string s = (string) Darray;
```

C# code that didn't create identical string to C++ code:

```
int length = Darray.Length * sizeof(double);
IntPtr pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length );
Marshal.Copy(Darray, 0, pnt, Darray.Length);
byte[] Barray = new byte[length];
Marshal.Copy(pnt, Barray, 0, length);
string theString = BitConverter.ToString(Barray);
```

C# code that also didn't create identical string to C++ code:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
{
    formatter.Serialize(m, Darray);
    m.Position = 0;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(m);
    string theString = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

C# code that also didn't create identical string to C++ code:

```
byte[] theBytesData = new byte[numBytesReqd];
Buffer.BlockCopy(Darray, 0, theBytesData, 0, numBytesReqd);
string theString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(theBytesData, 0, theBytesData.Length);
```

Maybe there is no solution to this problem other than a mixed language program.

For the following C++ code:

```
    double Darray[] = { 1.0,2.0,3.0 };
    char* DarrayCp = (char*)Darray;
    for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++)
    {
        cout << i << "\tDarrayCp: " << DarrayCp[i] << endl;
    }
```

I get the following output which I'd like to reproduce with C# code:

```
0   DarrayCp:  
1   DarrayCp:  
2   DarrayCp:  
3   DarrayCp:  
4   DarrayCp:  
5   DarrayCp:  
6   DarrayCp: ð
7   DarrayCp: ?
8   DarrayCp:  
9   DarrayCp:  
10  DarrayCp:  
11  DarrayCp:  
12  DarrayCp:  
13  DarrayCp:  
14  DarrayCp:  
15  DarrayCp: @
16  DarrayCp:  
17  DarrayCp:  
18  DarrayCp:  
19  DarrayCp:  
20  DarrayCp:  
21  DarrayCp:  
22  DarrayCp: 
23  DarrayCp: @
```

Comment: A C# `string` is *very* different from a C++ `char*` you can't just cast to it

Comment: You misunderstand what's happening in C++ when you cast an array to `char*`. You do not create a string, you simply treat it as a sequence of bytes. I am still very unclear what you are trying to do, so I can't offer any more guidance.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand what happens in C++ when I cast an array to char*. It was something that a contractor did many years ago. I'm trying to replace the C++ code with C# code that will produce the same string. I have C++ code that I want to keep that process it in the reverse direction (char* to double array) so the string needs to be the same whether produced by the C# or C++ code. Thanks for looking at it. Sorry I didn't make it clear enough.

Comment: @BobC. You describe what you wanted to do on a high-level, so why are you wasting time looking at C++ code to do this when you're trying to do this in C#?

Comment: I need to produce the same string from C# that the C++ code produces because I have a large body of calculation code in C++ that retrieves the doubles as a string from the database memo field. I have a large body of C++ software (GUI, database) that currently uses the cast to char* that I want to replace with the C# software. I was only using the C++ software to demonstrate the string that I need to produce.

Comment: @BobC Maybe look for similar issues, such as how does C# send and receive an array of doubles over a socket?  I'm sure it would be similar, and if so, forget about C++ at that point.  Also, shouldn't you start by attempting to read the existing data from the database in C#, to see if you're even on the right track?  Writing the data is secondary, IMO.

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiar with sockets so I'll look into it. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just reinterpreting the raw bytes in the C++ code, the output characters you're seeing depend on the encoding used by the console or whatever other output method you're using to test the C++ code.

It looks like ISO-8859-1 gives you the same output as the sample you posted:

```
var Darray = new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
var bytes = new byte[Darray.Length * sizeof(double)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(Darray, 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
var str = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(bytes);
```

but it's unclear to me if this conversion is actually useful for whatever you're trying to accomplish, since `string` and `char` in C# use UTF-16 characters so the resulting `str` has a completely different byte representation. `bytes` already represents the same data as `DarrayCp` in your C++ source, without any conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It looks like the different byte representation doesn't allow the conversion back to the C++ code that reads the string out of the database and copies it to a double array. I appreciate your help.